# AWS deployment of django application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I have a django application which has been deployed in aws. The URL in ec2 instance is loading fine too.
My application has a modal where I should enter my team name and username. Whenever I try in **[ec2instanceurl]:8000/** (when i start gunicorn)iam not facing any alert error.

But when i start the nginx and access the url without port(8000) the page is loading and whenever i enter the details in modal and click confirm button it shows an alert says '[ec2instanceurl] says error'

I will attach the error snap here

I want to know whether it is my django app error or any aws settings error.
The thing is that its working fine in local,and in gunicorn port.[image]

Though Iam new to aws deployment iam expecting advices..
Thanks in advance

nginx config file (/etc/nginx/sites-available)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ec2-34-232-78-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

  location / {
     include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/rest_project/app.sock;
    }
}
```

gunicorn conf file

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/ubuntu/rest_project
command=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/rest_project/app.sock rest_project.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log

[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

logs of nginx (error log)
[image]
access log
[image]

```
gunicorn command:

gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 rest_project.wsgi:application
```

Comment: Can you please add your nginx configuration to the original post? Also, you can ssh to your EC2 and check nginx logs for more details.

Comment: I added config file and i checked error log also. It is not showing any errors.It is showing only one status "signal process started"

Comment: You checked nginx logs? Can you share a snapshot of nginx logs which are generated when you submit the form in frontend? Also, your gunicorn config or the command you have used to run gunicorn.

Comment: Open your browser's network inspector and look at the request and response for starters.

Comment: @Rajesh Yogeshwar  I added logs,commands in original post.

Comment: This looks fine in first instance, did you also check log files that you have setup in gunicorn config?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I checked that also ..but didnot found any errors

Comment: @deceze     i found error in network console jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 POST http://ec2-34-232-78-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com/video/video-stream/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: That ain't helping. You need to dig into the right log files to figure out what the actual error is.

Comment: It actually feels like it needs a screenshare to debug it remotely :D But @deceze is right, this isn't much helpful, you need to check minor details, log files for gunicorn.

Comment: For now i checked nginx and gunicorn log files. Is there any other logs that i need to check and verify? @deceze